How to expose a List<Interface> when myClass has List<Class That Implements This Interface>? (C#)
I want to create a read-only interface for my Box class. Box contains bananas. Bananas have a read-only interface IBananaRead.
The problem is, that in the box code I do all operations with List<Banana> but in the read only interface I want the other class to have access not to Banana but to IBananaReads. How to solve this type of situations?
class Box: IBoxRead
 {
List<Banana> bananas;
}

interface IBoxRead {
List<IBananaRead> bananas;
}

I could create a duplicate list of IBananaRead interfaces in the Box but that doesn't seem right due to duplication.
class Box: IBoxRead
 {
List<Banana> bananas;
List<IBananaRead> bananaReads;
}

interface IBoxRead {
List<IBananaRead> bananaReads;
}


The end goal is to have two types of interactions with the Box:
// A read-only class iterates over:
foreach (IBananaRead b in instanceOfBoxRead.bananas) 
{
  b.ReadTheBanana();
}

// Another class that has right to edit the bananas in the box iterates
// using the class Banana, not the readonly interface of IBananaRead:
foreach (Banana b in instanceOfBox.bananas) 
{
  b.EditTheBanana();
}


Looking at the last box: Do you expect the solution to be Thread-Safe?

Something like this is possible: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KOWMEs but it wouldn't support concurrent (mutational) iteration of the wrapped list.

First of all, your IBoxRead interface cannot be compiled.

Ask yourself whether exposing a list, which can be modified, is what you're actually trying to achieve here. Do you really want callers to be able to insert SomethingElseThatImplementsIBananaRead objects into this list?

Ideallly, consumers wouldn't even know that there is a List<T> (whatever T actually is) inside the Box.

And as always: Mind that for the compiler List<MyClass> and List<MyInterface> are two distinct and unrelated types even if MyClass : MyInterface.

^^ Ah in my above fiddle I may have fallen for a misunderstanding. What exactly shall be "readonly"? The reference to the list, the list or the items of the list or a combination thereof?

Covariance and contravariance in generics | Microsoft Learn
A List<T> or IList<T> is, by definition, invariant. You can't pass it around as an IList<U> for either T : U or U : T.
If you could:

For T : U, you could insert an instance of V, where V : U, which would mean the List<T> would contain an item which was not an instance of T.
For U : T, you could have a List<U> containing items which are not instances of U.

In this case, you want a covariant list. That means you need to use the IReadOnlyList<T> interface, which is implemented by the List<T> class. You can happily return a List<T> as IReadOnlyList<U> when T : U.
However, a property of type List<T> cannot implicitly implement an interface property of type IReadOnlyList<T>, so you would need to implement that property explicitly. The explicit implementation can simply delegate to the List<T> property.
This would give you:
interface IBoxRead
{
    IReadOnlyList<IBananaRead> Bananas { get; }
}

class Box : IBoxRead
{
    public List<Banana> Bananas { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<IBananaRead> IBoxRead.Bananas => Bananas;
}

NB: This pattern would not prevent consumers of the IBoxRead interface from directly casting the property to List<Banana> and modifying the list. But by the same argument, they could also cast the IBoxRead instance to a Box, which would give them the same access.

Thanks! The NB part is important. The way it's set up at the moment, a consumer of IBoxRead can not access any instance of Banana. The references to Banana are accessible but a reference to Box is not exposed. Imagine that it's really really important that they don't access any Banana. In fact the whole existance of the read only interface is to make sure they never access the Banana. Being able to cast IBananaRead to Banana would defeat some of that safeguard. I want to cast Banana to IBananaRead freely but not the other way around. I should probably read the article. Thanks again!

@luminous As I said, they could still cast the IBoxRead instance to Box. If you could make the Box and Banana classes internal, that would make it harder to do (although still not impossible). If that's a concern, you'd need a full read-only wrapper for both classes, which would mean the consumer would have to use reflection to get at the mutable instances.

@luminous Do I get that right that you need to at least consider malicious intent on the side of your clients? That part would have been kind of important to add to the question.

@Fildor I don't consider malicious intent but the application is a deterministic simulation. Any accidental editing of a Banana will break the determinism. Hence the read only interface. But no malicious intent, just really bad results of an accidental editing. Furthermore the issue will usually appear long after the edit was made, making it very hard to track down later what went wrong in the determinism. There are tests in place to find such issues quickly but the read-only interface is important second layer of defense.

Ok. What I was presupposing was that if you provide a Readonly API and a client goes on to "unreadonly" it - that's bordering on malicious intent in my book. You clearly don't want the client to modify which you express in using a R/O API. Does it make sense? That said: If they still go on to forcefully mutate and that breaks the app - blame is on them. Different story in a banking system or something like that, where you always should expect the most malicious intent from clients.

Unless I'm missing something, all you need is this:
var boxList = new List<Box>();

// ...

var iBoxReadList = boxList.Cast<IBoxRead>().ToList();

That would need to be executed on demand, i.e. each time you need a list of read-only items, as it will not be updated along with the original list. You could declare a read-only property and create the new list in the getter.
That said, the second list should probably be read-only too, rather than just the items. Otherwise, the consumer could add items to the list to no good effect. In that case, you should probably do this:
var iBoxReadList = boxList.Cast<IBoxRead>().ToList().AsReadOnly();

That will create a ReadOnlyCollection<IBoxRead>.

If you're going to return a read-only list, you could make the return type IReadOnlyList<IBoxRead> and return the boxList directly.

@Fildor Why not? List<Box> implements IReadOnlyList<Box>, and the IReadOnlyList<T> interface is covariant, so List<Box> is implicitly convertible to IReadOnlyList<IBoxRead>. :)

@RichardDeeming Ah, missed the covariance. Comment retracted!
